# I assume we like hats?

Tags: discussion

With the ending of the current year, we have the option to participate in the 2016 Stack Exchange Winter Bash.  This basically means we'll have the opportunity to earn hats by participating on the site in various, usually hidden ways, and then the option to decorate our avatars with our earned hats.

When the bash is over we loose our hats.

We have until the 13th to decide, but I assume we want in, right?

Comment: Squeek now or forever hold your cheese...

Comment: Sure, let's do it

Comment: I just assumed we would.  It's a fun thing

Comment: Upvoting this so as to get a hat, so yes :-)

Comment: @Graphus Me too.